# fixing css for ie6 need help!

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have been trying very hard to achieve rounded corners with IE6+jquery ui tabs.

I have this page prepared: http://jsbin.com/uzoko (w/out dd_roundies)

Ofcourse, the rounded corners work in FF but not IE6.  Because some of the properties used in CSS are specific to FF and Chrome.

I had asked this question yesterday [image: as well] and based on that suggestion I used the DD_Roundies library.  However, the sample page I provided up top doesnt have the ability to add DD_Roundies library so I cant really 'show' what exactly is wrong with the page when it is openeing in css.

But after implementing DD_Roundies I can see the rounded corners in IE6 fine.  HOWEVER, I have following problems:

1. ONLY the 'First' tabs seems to have rounded corners. When i click on second tab, it doesnt have rounded corners and so doesnt the third.
2. when I move away from First tab, it seems to have a border with color #990000.

All of this does not happen in FF @#$%@$!!

Since I am unable to put DD_Roundies library code in jsbin I will put what I have relative to dd_roundies on my page, here:

```
        DD_roundies.addRule('.ui-corner-all', '4px');
        DD_roundies.addRule('.ui-corner-top', '2px 2px 0px 0px');
        DD_roundies.addRule('.ui-corner-bottom', '0 0 4px 4px');
        DD_roundies.addRule('.ui-corner-right', '0 4px 4px 0');
        DD_roundies.addRule('.ui-corner-left', '4px 0 0 4px');
        DD_roundies.addRule('.ui-corner-tl', '4px 0 0 0');
        DD_roundies.addRule('.ui-corner-tr', '0 4px 0 0');
        DD_roundies.addRule('.ui-corner-br', '0 0 4px 0');
        DD_roundies.addRule('.ui-corner-bl', '0 0 0 4px');
```

I am not good at CSS to begin with and then correcting css so it works with freaking ie6 is whole another battle that I can use some help in.  Please!

Also, as suggested in the question I asked yesterday, I tried using images as well.  I used cornershop website to create two rounded corner images.  http://tinypic.com/r/30j1rgz/5 and http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=50joqq&s=5 but with these when  I changed 'Interaction States' section of the css and property `.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited` to the following

```
background: #990000; 
font-weight: bold; 
color: #ffffff; 
text-decoration: none; 
outline: none;
background: url(nw.gif) no-repeat top left; 
background: url(ne.gif) no-repeat top right;
```

then I got even weirder restuls :(

Comment: +1 sympathy for working with IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, after 2 hours of work, i gave up useing DD_roundies,

it just doesn't work well with combination with the Tabs UI.

Then I tried [another plugin](http://jrc.meerbox.nl/) which I know should work, and tested on:

**IE6, IE7, FF3**

all works well!

[**See demo here**](http://jsbin.com/ozoge)

I've also modified your CSS.

put the whole  "*Corner radius*" section on comment. no need for that.

Hope this suits your needs :)